# Ballerina - Unable to build Docker image

Tags: ballerina

Hi after installing ballerina using this build

https://product-dist.ballerina.io/nightly/0.981.1-SNAPSHOT/ballerina-platform-linux-installer-x64-0.981.1-SNAPSHOT.rpm

I wasn't able to generate a docker image from my ballerina code:

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;
import ballerinax/docker;

endpoint http:Listener PessoasEP {
port: 9095,
secureSocket: {
    keyStore: {
        path: "${ballerina.home}/bre/security/ballerinaKeystore.p12",
        password: "ballerina"
    }
}
};

@http:ServiceConfig {
basePath: "/"
}
@docker:Config {
registry:"devcamp2018",
name:"pessoas-docker",
tag:"1.0"
}
service getPessoas bind PessoasEP {
@http:ResourceConfig {
    methods: ["GET"],
    path: "/pessoas"
}    
getPessoas(endpoint caller, http:Request req) {
    http:Response res = new;

    json p2 = [
        {
            fname: "Joao",
            lname: "Silva"
        },{
            fname: "Roberto",
            lname: "Monteiro"
        }
    ];

    res.setPayload(p2);
    caller->respond(res) but {
        error e => log:printError("Error in responding ", err = e) 
    };
}
}
```

Is there anything else that has to be done other than installing ballerina?

Comment: Did you see any errors? Were you able to find any error logs in ballerina-internal.log?

Comment: Have you installed docker? What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [Ballerina](https://ballerina.io/downloads/) and [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/) only. Then execute the following command to create the ballerina executable file with docker image.

**NOTE**: Create a `sample.bal` file with the given code sample

```
$ ballerina run sample.bal
```

The output will be as follows:

```
Compiling source
    sample.bal

Generating executable
    sample.balx
        @docker                  - complete 3/3 

        Run the following command to start a Docker container:
        docker run -d devcamp2018/pessoas-docker:1.0
```

Created Docker image can be listed by executing `$ docker images`

```
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
devcamp2018/pessoas-docker           1.0                 586bedf394bc        About an hour ago   127MB
```